# How to navigate one page to another automatically using Spring MVC or other Spring project?

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc

Suppose I have two pages: 1) payment page, 2) payment successful page. User can a) finish payment on payment page or b) scan the QR Code on this page then finish payment through the app in his Smart Phone. After the payment I want to navigate user from page 1) to page 2) which is payment successful page.

My question is how can I accomplish this under situation b)? One possible approach I can think of is that I put an timer on page 1) and check the order status through ajax call every few seconds. Navigate to page 2) once the payment is done. Is there any other better approach? Can the back end drive the navigation instead of checking status from front end? Is there any framework/project under Spring I can use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

well for me there are 3 different approaches i can imagine right now.

1. as described by you; using ajax to periodically check
2. design my "user-flow/page-flow" in that way that the user chooses what specific payment method he wants to use and redirect him to the one or the other page.
3. using web-sokets from spring-io to send a signal to the browser to forward the page (see here https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/)